# writing a logic to check if value exists

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, lucee

working on the data returned by code

Trying to add some logic that if the value exists, show it else put empty

```
<cfset myStruct = {
    "access_token" : "#st.access_token#",
    "id": "#res.names[1].metadata.source.id#",
    "name" : "#isDefined('res.names') ? res.names[1].displayname : ''#",
    "other" : {
        "email" : "#res.emailAddresses[1].value#"
    }
}>
```

Open in new window

its not clean and it throws error on line 3 which is ID, so what kind of isDefined or structkeyexists i can write if it exists add it, else put an empty value

Comment: `throws error on line 3...` That type of statement should always be followed by the actual error message.

Comment: Life would be simpler if you checked for the existence of the variable before trying to use it rather than trying to do it all at once.  Your question shows two ways of doing this.  A third is `<cfparam>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Elvis operator](https://docs.lucee.org/guides/developing-with-lucee-server/operators.html#elvis-operator)

Edit: Unless you really need the values as a string, you do not need to use pounds to output the values

Edit 2: Have updated the example to use the right comment

```
<cfset myStruct = {
      "access_token" : "#st.access_token#" <!--- If you have numeric token and need it to be a string --->
    , "id"           : res.names[ 1 ].metadata.source.id ?: ""
    , "name"         : res.names[ 1 ].displayname        ?: ""
    , "other"        : {
        "email" : res.emailAddresses[ 1 ].value ?: ""
    }
}>
```

Comment: True. Maybe update the example to demonstrate how they don't need `IsDefined()` (or all those extra pound signs #) either ? (:

Comment: IT WILL NOT WORK FOR COLDUSION 11

Comment: No need to shout! What version are you using, Lucee or CF11? Your question tags have both.

Comment: ok, first of all i do not know writing in caps case is shouting, My first native language is not English, so i did not mean to harm any person's sentiments

Comment: I am using Coldfusion 11

Comment: The code works with CF11. Did you remove the comment line i.e. `"...// If you have numeric token....to be a string"`? https://trycf.com/gist/298e1a1803cd50e40ab2ab08ed6c36b1/acf11?theme=monokai